# Inconsistent internal package errors with go get

Tags: go, etcd

I'm trying to `go get go.etcd.io/etcd/tools/benchmark`.

Previously this has worked, flawlessly. However when I try to do it currently I have alternatively got no errors and I've had it fail on me with:

```
go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/balancer_conn_wrappers.go:28:2: use of internal package google.golang.org/grpc/internal/buffer not allowed
go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:49:2: use of internal package google.golang.org/grpc/internal/resolver/dns not allowed
go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:50:2: use of internal package google.golang.org/grpc/internal/resolver/passthrough not allowed
```

The first time I ran it on a new `go-1.13` installation it worked, but the following times it has failed as above.

The repo has not changed as far as I can tell in the past 8 months and I've tried on various `golang` versions but all so far have failed (bar the `go-1.13` on that first try...).

Any assistance debugging this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like an issue with the `go.etcd.io/etcd/tools/benchmark` package missing vendored packages. If you use modules and ignore vendor it will probably work (set `GO111MODULE=on` if you're working in `GOPATH`)

Comment: This appears to be a problem with etcd. A member of the gRPC Go team [just filed an issue on their repo for it](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/11553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both a workaround and an official fix.

The workaround:

Here I defined a go.mod which then used a previous version of the library.

The official fix:

This was fixed upstream and thus no one else should experience this.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can try by removing *vendor* folder from the `go.etcd.io/etcd repo`. Also disable the `vendoring mode`. It should work.